# If cell ranging from A1:A5000 contains (e.g. 001) then the next cell (B2) should input a "certain text"

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

hello beginner coder here would like to get a bit of help since I'm stumped trying to code it,
tried using

```
=IF(A1:A5000)="001","Certain Text")
```

but since I'm getting 38 of that "Certain Text" I tried copying the code 38 times but kept getting an error. Appreciate any help I can get.

Thank you.

Comment: Try placing the next formula in B1 and then, fill it down: `=IF(A1 ="001","Certain Text")`

Comment: You place bracket wrongly try `=IF(A1:A5000="001","Certain Text")` In office-365 result will be automatically spill.

Answer (score -1):

Dim A As Range
set SpecialTexts = "001"

For Each A In [A:A].SpecialTexts(xlCellTypeTexts, 1).Offset(0, +1).Areas
A.insert Application.worksheetFunction.text("Certain Text")

Next

Comment: How does this answer the question?